# Reading the parameters of an ajax link in PHP in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am new with Ajax. I have a link which has *4 parameters* one of these is `$str_post` which is initialized in controller:

```
$str_post="&ajax =1";
$str_post.="&province=".$this->input->post('province');
$str_post.="&city=".$this->input->post('city');
$str_post.="&name=".$this->input->post('name');     
$this->ajax_pagination->make_search($this->case_model->case_paginations(),$starting,$url,$str_post);
```

By using this function(make_search) it sets the `$str_post` as the parameters of Ajax pagination link. When I echo `$str_post` it is some thing like this:

```
&ajax=1&proince=all&city=all&name=all
```

Now I need to get these parameters and assign every of them in another variables like this:

```
$province=$str_post['province'];
```

But it shows just `&` how can I get the `all` value?
Can any one help me?

Comment: `$str_post` is not an array!

Comment: If the ajax type is GET. Just try $_GET['ajax'];

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the values this way!

```
$province = $_POST['province']; // if the ajax type is post
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse the query string, this is what you do,

```
$get_string = "&ajax=1&proince=all&city=all&name=all";

parse_str($get_string, $get_array);

print_r($get_array);
```

Or if you just want the get array inside a variable,

```
$get_array = $this->input->get(null, true); //here $get_string is an array with get data
print_r($get_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter, you can use get function. Something like this:

```
$province = $this->input->get('province');
```

You can use 'get' when you are using query string on your URL formatting.